# baking normal map artifacts

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

I am having artifacts when doing bake in substance painter and also in blender, I do not know if this is normal.
[image]

have high poli baked to low poly, here are the UVS
[image: UV layout]

Comment: could you also upload a wireframe of your actual model? is the beveled edge in the normal map, or do you really have geometry there? also: please add a screenshot from your UV-editor, so we can see if any seams are too close to eachother. That also can create artifacts.